# Jquery Detecting ScrollTop

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a sticky menu, the only issue is when I scroll up the removeClass get triggered

```
 $(window).bind('scroll',function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll > 50 ) {

        $('.menu').addClass( 'sticky' );
    } else {

         $('.menu').removeClass('sticky');
    }

});
```

Comment: I'm going to suggest that you read [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), which explains how to set up a runnable example here in your post. Then, I'm going to suggest that you put a working example of your problem here in the post. That will make it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: If your condition is `scrollTop greater than 50` and you scroll to top where this is false, you indeed remove the class. What did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You could check if scroll is up or down, so that it is only removed when scrolling down.
Like this:

```
var lastScroll = 0;
$(window).bind('scroll',function() {
   var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
   if(scroll > lastScroll) {
      if(scroll > 50 ) {
         $('.menu').addClass( 'sticky' );
      } else {
         $('.menu').removeClass('sticky');
      }
   }
   lastScroll = scroll;
});
```

If scroll is bigger than lastScroll, you are scrolling down.